# C++ #include <atlbase.h> is not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi

When I compile my C++ program in Visual Studio Express it says that it can't find `atlbase.h`. Am I missing some SDK or something?

Comment: As Matteo alluded to, ATL is not included with the Express edition.

Comment: ATL is now a part of build tools https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/announcing-the-official-release-of-the-visual-c-build-tools-2015/

Comment: @highmaintenance The page is not found.

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro: it was https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments/ "MFC and ATL (added with VS 2015 Update 3)"

Comment: Related: [MFC development in vs2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43074045/3357935)

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro See the wayback machine https://web.archive.org/web/20190117225943/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/announcing-the-official-release-of-the-visual-c-build-tools-2015/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Microsoft ATL (Active Template Library), which includes the header `atlbase.h` is included with the [Windows 2003 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=0BAF2B35-C656-4969-ACE8-E4C0C0716ADB&displaylang=en), but it is not included with any newer Windows SDK release. It is also included with Professional editions of Visual Studio.

Comment: which one of the three files should i download

Comment: `PSDK-amd64.exe` if you are running 64-bit Windows on an x86-64 CPU. `PSDK-ia64.exe` if you are running Windows on Itanium. `PSDK-x86.exe` if you are running 32-bit Windows.

Comment: Well, link doesn't exist anymore. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8990680/353410) seems to work

Answer (score 69):

**Visual Studio 2017**

When running the Visual Studio Installer, select the **Individual components** tab, and under *SDKs, libraries, and frameworks* make sure **Visual C++ ATL Support** is selected.
[image: VS Installer Visual C++ ATL Support selected]

Comment: I did the above but it didn't end up on the path so I added it.  For me, it was: D:\Visual Studio 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\include

Comment: Between the highlighted with yellow there also is "MFC and ATL support (x86 and x64)" item, which might need to be checked as well.

Comment: Installing ATL didn't fix the issue in Visual Studio Community 2017. This may only work in VS Professional.

Comment: The same is available for VS 19, both for the v141 (VS 17) and v142 (VS 19) toolchains.

Comment: @StevoisiaksupportsMonica this works for Visual Studio 2017 Express, which is in the OP's question. But this is incomplete. First of all you install Visual Studio 2017 BuildTools and select Visual C++ ATL for x64. Then you go into the directory and copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc` to VSDExpress folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023`. Then the tools can find the source files. See @pogosama's answer.

Answer (score 40):

It is included with the [Windows Driver Kit Version 7.1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11800).

Comment: I have just used this solution. By far the best answer. For some reason I had to download the ISO, though, but hosted that with Daemon Tools and no problems installing it. Not only does it give you the header (`atlbase.h`) and libs (e.g. `atls.lib`), the next missing lib I needed was `ws2_32.lib` and it was also included with a whole host of others. Don't bother with the old SDKs, and you certainly don't need to upgrade your Express Visual Studio edition as so many people suggest at first.

Comment: I have downloaded this driver kit but couldn't figure out how to give path of atlbase.h in project. Asked a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906033/including-files-or-headers-outside-the-windows-kit) also.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution for Visual Studio 2017 Express edition**

I had the same error when building a COM C++ project in Visual Studio 2017 Express edition. As mentioned by several users here, ATL support is not included with the Express edition of Visual Studio. So to build a C++ COM/ATL project you need at least the *Community edition*.

If you really need to use the Express edition, you can download and install the [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools). Make sure to enable the '**Visual C++ ATL for x86 and x64**' component during the setup.

After that add additional VC++ directories in the project properties:

- Include directories: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\atlmfc\include`
- Library directories: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\atlmfc\lib\x86`

The VC++ compiler should now be able to find the ATL source and library files.

Answer (score 5):

For users of Visual Studio 2015, ensure Common Tools for C++ is installed (part of the VS installer).

Answer (score 4):

update for visual studio community 2022:

1. open visual studio installer.

   you can search it on start
2. modify installed version

[image]

3. search atl and install.

   if you are not sure about the version, go to install directory to check it.

   for example my directory has 14.33, so I choose v14.33, if there are multiple versions, install them all, or you can try one by one.

   D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Situation

With Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, we installed "Visual C++ ATL support" and MFC and ATL support. The error still occurred in our x64 project.

### Solution

We fixed some paths with the following two commands:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>mklink /d atlmfc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\lib>mklink /d amd64 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\lib\x64
```

### Details

We eventually found the header `atlbase.h` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\include`. This path simply was not added to the VC Include directory by `vsvars32.bat`, so the header was not found during build.

vsvars32.bat includes the following line:

```
@if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%ATLMFC\INCLUDE" set INCLUDE=%VCINSTALLDIR%ATLMFC\INCLUDE;%INCLUDE%`.
```

This resolved to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include` in our machine.

We created a directory junction, so the build tool finds `atlbase.h` in the expected directory (this is the first command from the Solution section above):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>mklink /d atlmfc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc"
```

Afterwards, the linker did not find `atls.lib` (see [Cannot Open File atls.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123088)). This was due to the expected file structure was that `lib` should directly contain the x86 version of the libs and `lib\amd64` should contain the x64 variants. Instead, `lib\x86` contained the x86 versions and `lib\x64` contained the 64 bit versions. Since we build a 64 bit project, creating another directory junk from amd64 to x64 solved the problem:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\lib>mklink /d amd64 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\lib\x64
```

Comment: This method didn't survive the latest Visual Studio update, as the ATL SDK updated to 14.14.26428 and so the paths changed. After updating the symlink paths, it worked again.

Answer (score 2):

That header appears to be a part of the [Windows Platform SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2008/02/22/using-visual-c-2008-express-with-the-windows-sdk-short-version.aspx).

You should search your computer for the file.  That will tell you if you're missing it.

Comment: It was included in older versions of the Windows Platform SDK, but it is (apparently intentionally) omitted from current ones.

Comment: atlbase.h file only come up with community edition , trying to download from other SDK is waste of time , because all other SDK links are not found. Is it correct?

Comment: For me, Visual Studio (2022) Tools->'Get Tools and Features' did it.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with sample project. I specified the sample project's properties and the sample project compiled successfully.

Visual Studio 8
For header
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\atlmfc\include`

For `.lib` file
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\atlmfc\lib`

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet seen anyone mention Visual Studio 2015 (MSBuild 14.0). In this case I've had to download Visual C++ BuildTools (found here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/). After having installed this, running the installer again allowed me to modify the installation and include the ATL libs.

Hope this helps anyone that is still using MSBuild 14.0