# ATLBase Include Doesn't Work

Tags: visual-c++, include, atl, visual-c++-2008-express

I searched my problem in StackOverflow, and I understood some of the ways to fix this - I guess. However, I couldn't accomplish this:

I have a project that was working in older versions of Microsoft Visual Studio. Now, I have to convert those projects to Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. I searched in StackOverflow about this and downloaded Windows SDK. I found this one in: [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898287/c-include-atlbase-h-is-not-found) and [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22668).

I also updated the directories that Visual C++ Express looks for when compiling my code, and updated those. I added the include and atl directories to VC++Express. However, my output windows still states that:

```
------ Build started: Project: myProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Compiling...
stdafx.cpp
c:\documents and settings\username\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\myProject\myProject\stdafx.h(16) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlbase.h': No such file or directory
Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myProject\myProject\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
myProject - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So, I beg your pardon if I did something wrong, and want you to give me some tips.

Thank you.

**Ninja Edit:** Do I have to download and install "Windows Driver Kit Version 7.1.0", too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ATL in VS Express Edition.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express

> Visual C++ Express
>
> The Visual C++ Express Edition can be used to compile .NET as well as
>   Win32 applications. The Windows Platform SDK compilers and core files
>   are included which can be used to build applications that use the
>   Win32 API. **To build applications using either MFC or ATL, the
>   libraries have to be obtained from alternative sources** such as the
>   free-to-download Windows Driver Kit.

Comment: So, is there any way to include it? Some way to download it and include into my project?

Comment: WDK has ATL, though I am under impression that this is a copy of one of the old ATL versions (not sure).

Comment: And also, it's 600+MB. Can't I just include a tiny little atlbase.h to somewhere in my project and fix this?

Comment: What can I say, ATL is not present as a sort of free download, as far as I know. So you have no option to take this tiny file from. Maybe if your project is not so tightly using ATL (e.g. `CComPtr` wrappers only), you might be better off just re-implementing the missing classes.

Comment: ATL include is not a problem in non-Express editions, right? Like in Visual Studio? Thank you very much.

Comment: In non-express ATL is installed with Visual Studio and is automatically on include path. So `#include` works right out of the box.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. So, I'm really sorry, but what must I do for Express editions? Do you think installing WDK is the best thing to do? What about installing Windows SDK? I saw that there's ATL headers inside Windows SDK - that I linked in my question. Is there any way to include those atl headers into my project? Linking them inside Project Properties didn't work. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Windows SDK does not have it. Windows DDK possibly have it - you are to try if its ATL works out for you, or perhaps wait for someone to come in to share similar experience. DDK has *some* ATL, which might be or not be a solution for you to resolve the missing dependency.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know I talk too much, but Windows DDK integrates with Visual Studio. However, you said earlier that Visual Studio has ATL classes/headers. I have to compile my code on Express editions. You said there's no ATL headers in Windows SDK, but I think it has. Can you help me include those header files to my project which needs to be compiled under VC++ Express Edition? Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. Visual Studio (other than Express) - has it and installs automatically 2. Windows SDK does NOT have it 3. Windows DDK has AFAIR a copy of an older ATL version, if you install it you need to add certain directories to include/lib path under VS/project settings.

Comment: I did what you told, and I get new errors. [Can you help me on this one, too?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118898/atl-headers-in-visual-studio-express-editions) Thank you very much.