# Cannot Open File atls.lib

Tags: linker, atl, visual-c++-2008-express

I have atls.lib in my hard drive, but I can't link it into my Visual Studio project. I know that atls.lib is an ATL specific library file, and I have all the ATL files/headers/libraries. However, I still can't link them.

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'atls.lib'

Can anyone help a helpless programmer?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 20):

Fixed for me by installing the following Individual Component through the Visual Studio Installer:

- C++ ATL for latest v142 build tools with Spectre Mitigations (x86 & x64)

I'm running a 32 bit C# project using VS2019.

Comment: Thanks. You solution works. It is strange that the option "C++ ATL for latest v142 build tools  (x86 & x64)" doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @Hao it depends if /Qspectre option is set in your project or not

Answer (score 12):

In my case the problem was missing ATL/MFC libraries for x64, I had to add them in  the Visual Studio installer (it was an open source project, so I wasn't aware of the requirement).

Once again, the invaluable [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) did the job:
While *atls.lib* was found under `$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib` the linker looked in `$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\amd64`.

Answer (score 10):

Just to keep this question updated, I encountered this error after running the install for Spectre, the VC++ spec code mitigation tool.  After looking at the VC++ directories, I noticed that both the Include Directories and the Library Directories have changed to add a "Spectre" addition to the path, while the original path to the actual file is no longer there.  I will update this later after I figure out whether Spectre didn't install correctly, or if simply changing the path will solve the issue; I do NOT want the speculative attack exposed in my code, which apparently happens with ATL code.

**EDIT**

My compiler is VS 2017 Community Edition.

**EDIT**

The solution that worked for me is [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/253047/spectre-lib-folder-missing.html), discovered by Holger Schmeken

Comment: Thanks, basically we need spectre libs for ATL too!

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the library directory has not been added. In Project Properties, Linker, General options, add the directory where `atls.lib` resides to the `Additional Library Directories` field.

Comment: I solved it. I was included the library, but was still getting the error. It solved mystically. However, now I get [these errors.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123475/atl-based-linker-errors) Care to have a look? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I added `<Visual Studio folder\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\atlmfc\lib\x64\atls.lib>` to the `Linker>Input> Additional Dependencies`  in solution properties and it got resolved.

Comment: use the macro $(VCInstallDir).
So its $(VCInstallDir)Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\atlmfc\lib\x64\atls.lib

Comment: In VS 2019, because it is a lib file, make sure you added to correct setting: right click on project, select properties, under Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > **Library Directories**, add <Visual Studio 2019 folder>\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\atlmfc\lib\x86

Answer (score 1):

This issue started happening to me after a recent VS2019 update I got. I noticed that it was because Spectre Mitigation had been automatically enabled but I didn't have the Spectre Mitigation version of the library.

Installing the Spectre Mitigation version, or disabling Spectre Mitigation are both possible fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I have soloved this problem by just copying this file to my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2017, I fix this issue by installing this component:
*Visual C++ ATL (x86/x64) with Spectre Mitigations*

[image]