# Recyclerview - Top item should overlap next item and so on

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have set the negative margin for items like this:-

```
public class ItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int mSpace;

    public ItemDecorator(int space) {
        this.mSpace = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if (position != 0)
            outRect.top = mSpace;
    }
}
```

This causes top item to stack lowest and next item after the top item overlaps it. I want top item to overlap its next item and so on.

Comment: hey have you got any answer of this question, actually my requirement is same as this.

Comment: i will share you shortly. i have asked it from my other account and got answer there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40678937/4600792

Comment: this has been done bro but need to overlapping when scroll. i need functionality like this [https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView]  .check this link and when we scroll  all items overlapping to first item like card stack and so on.

Comment: the link you shared is 404.

Comment: sorry for that try this- https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView