# Recyclerview - Overlap items bottom to top

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have set the negative margin for items like this:-

**ItemDecoration.java**

```
public class ItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int mSpace;

    public ItemDecorator(int space) {
        this.mSpace = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if (position != 0)
            outRect.top = mSpace;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemDecorator(-80));
```

This causes top item to stack lowest and next item after the top item overlaps it. I want top item to overlap its next item and so on.

**Current View**

[image]

**Required View**

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this way and render your recycler view in reverse direction.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Here is the working example [GitHub Link](https://github.com/TasneemBohra/ItemDecoreStackOverFlow)

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: If someone is using Bilal's ItemDecorator, when you do this, the last card will be at the top. So make sure that the position you do not want the offset on, is not 0 but itemCount - 1. Also this top item will be item3, instead of item1

Comment: @Tasneem its showing reverse list first item is at last and last one is first

Comment: @Tasneem any solution for top item view overlap on bottom item view

Comment: @NikunjParadva , I did not get you. Could you please explain or problem more in detail.

Comment: example:- if arraylist is {1,2,3,4,5} then its shows as {5,4,3,2,1}

Comment: @NikunjParadva you have to reverse your input list to work or just ignore reversing and set z index for your items' view.

Answer (score 7):

As of 2020 there is new interface [ChildDrawingOrderCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ChildDrawingOrderCallback). It defines the order of drawing elements in recycler view. Can be used like so:

```
class BackwardsDrawingOrderCallback : RecyclerView.ChildDrawingOrderCallback {
    override fun onGetChildDrawingOrder(childCount: Int, i: Int) = childCount - i - 1
}
```

And then

```
recyclerView.setChildDrawingOrderCallback(BackwardsDrawingOrderCallback())
```

So there is no need to set neither reverse order nor stack from end anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve overlap is using margin with minus values inside recycler view item like so:

> image_item.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/authorIV"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_default_avatar"
    app:roundPercent="50" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create overlapping Ite Decorator by using:
Check this [link](https://medium.com/p/29651f6fa564)

```
class OverlappingItemDecoration : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, - 60)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try overriding this method.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. really appreciate it. I think you miss understood my question. i have added pictures for better understanding of my requirement. Please have a look.