# RecyclerView with stack item(overlapping)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overlap

[image]

I need recycler view where each next item below previous one. It should overlap somehow. Is it possible using recyclerview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recyclerview - Overlap items bottom to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677024/recyclerview-overlap-items-bottom-to-top)

Comment: see this lib https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to add ItemdDecorator:

```
public class ItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int mSpace;

    public ItemDecorator(int space) {
        this.mSpace = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        outRect.right = -mSpace;
    }
}
```

And then while initializing recycler view:

```
binding.containerAction.rvGroupCallUserList.addItemDecoration(new ItemDecorator(80));
```