# Visual Studio exhibits inconsistent behavior in Create a new C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit), **Version** **17.1.6** according to VS *Help->About* but **17.3.2** according to VS Installer, on Windows 10. I've been programming in C# for some time and decided to try C++.

I downloaded the workload *Desktop development with C++* through *VS Installer->Modify*. But I cannot see the C++ project templates in the *Create a new project* form. 
[image]

If I click *Next* in the above form, a C# project is created. Using VS Installer I

- run *Repair* VS
- uninstalled *Desktop development with C++*
- installed *Desktop development with C++* again.

**When I start VS from VS *Installer->Launch***, I get a long list of C++ templates.
[image]

But when starting VS directly, without Installer, no templates are found.

Comment: ¿Perhaps you are switching to different user?

Comment: Most (if not all) of the Windows desktop templates require that you install MFC, which you have to install individually, not as part of a workload. Slightly dated but still roughly accurate directions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43075169/179910

Comment: @user7860670: No, I'm not.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Thank you, I''ll look at it. But it does not explain why I cannot see the project templates **if** VS is started directly.

Comment: Was the first picture opened with **Blend For Visual Studio**?

Comment: @Minxin Yu - MSFT: I did open Blend For Visual Studio for a while. But I closed it and the PC was restarted after VS Repair. The reported problem occured both before Repair-Restart and after Repair-Restart. The problem exists in Visual Studio, I did't try to use Blend For Visual Studio, I only opened it shotly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for this behavior. I start VS using an icon (shortcut) pinned to start in Windows 10. This icon was pointing at an old version of VS. When VS was updated and a new workload was added, this icon still pointed to the old VS version.

I removed this icon and created a new one, and everything works fine now.

A VS shortcut points at *..\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe*. In my case, there were two copies of this file tree; one under C:\Program Files\ and the other under D:. The other was correct, but at some update VS Installer neglected this configuration and selected the C: drive by default.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)