# Fatal Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlbase.h' Pyinsane package

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, pyinsane

So after downloading the pyinsane 2.0.2 package from [here](https://github.com/jflesch/pyinsane/archive/2.0.2.zip) and going in to the command window, I ran the `setup.py build` command. But everytime I run it, the fatal Error C1083 comes up:

```
rawapi.cpp
src/pyinsane2/wia/rawapi.cpp(8): fatal error C 1083: Cannot open include file: 
'atlbase.h': 
no such file or directory 
error: command 'C\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\
Visual Studio\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\
HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I know this question got asked in quite similar ways many times before, but none of them were about the pyinsane Package or the atlbase.h file, I'm dealing with. 
If I just haven't found the right question, a link to it woukd be much appreciated.

And yes, I have already tried just using `#include <atlbase>` but it gave me the same error. 
I am using python 3.6.3 on Windows 8.1 with MC VS 2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know this question got asked in quite similar ways many times before, but none of them were about the pyinsane Package or the atlbase.h.

Had you really searched the solution? The first search attempt in Google results the first link to [C++ #include <atlbase.h> is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898287/c-include-atlbase-h-is-not-found)

> When running the Visual Studio Installer, select the **Individual components** tab, and under SDKs, libraries, and frameworks make sure **Visual C++ ATL Support** is selected.