# ungoogled-chromium-windows build fails with "fatal error: 'atlsecurity.h' file not found"

Tags: python, c++, windows, chromium, ninja

I've been trying to build ungoogled-chromium-windows using their build.py file. Unfortunately, during processing of about 40,000 files, it crashes after around 11,000. This is the command that the build file runs and ultimately fails:

```
"third_party\ninja\ninja.exe" "-C" "out\Default" "chrome" "chromedriver" "mini_installer"
ninja: Entering directory `out\Default'
[11350/41090] CXX obj/chrome/elevation_service/lib/service_main.obj
FAILED: obj/chrome/elevation_service/lib/service_main.obj
```

But the main issue seems to come from its inability to locate atlsecurity.h file, which from what I understand should be in some of the Windows SDK that I downloaded. This is the error it generates:

```
../../chrome/elevation_service/service_main.cc(14,10): fatal error: 'atlsecurity.h' file not found
#include <atlsecurity.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[11367/41090] CXX obj/components/dom_distiller/core/proto/proto/distilled_page.pb.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Work\Projects\ungoogled-chromium-windows\build\src>exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 221, in <module>
    main()
  File "build.py", line 216, in main
    _run_build_process('third_party\\ninja\\ninja.exe', '-C', 'out\\Default', 'chrome',
  File "build.py", line 64, in _run_build_process
    subprocess.run(('cmd.exe', '/k'),
  File "C:\depot_tools\bootstrap-3_8_0_chromium_8_bin\python3\bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('cmd.exe', '/k')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I thought MinGW was causing an issue with the ninja command but nothing seems to let me get further than this step so far. Let me know if I can give any more information to aid. This is the github for the chromium build I'm using: https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-windows

Comment: Active Template Library? Wow, that's old stuff, I believe I didn't hear about that the last 2 decades.

Comment: Does this help a bit? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898287/c-include-atlbase-h-is-not-found

Comment: I can't seem to download an old Windows SDK?

Comment: I am not sure if it even would work properly if you could.